USB Mic not showing up but it is getting power
On my Framework 16, running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS.
I just bought a t.Bone SC430 USB microphone. Unfortunately I cannot get the microphone to be detected. The mute and unmute indicator light however is working/ lighting up, so the mic is at least getting power.
lsusb returns every device but not the microphone. udevadm monitor does not show any sign of a usb device that is being connected if i connect the mic after starting the monitor. demsg also has no entry for connecting or disconnecting the microphone. (tried it with a usb mouse and got info about it being disconnected and connecting again). with the lshw command output i also cannot find anything related to the microphone.
I tried using 3 different cables (A to C, C to C) on all available ports of the laptop. Nothing. Connecting the microphone to my samsung mobile phone does show a USB connector connected notification.
As the device is showing up on my android phone, I'm not sure if the mic is broken or the OS of my laptop is causing the issue.
Any help will be appreciated. If someone needs further diagnostics information, please let me know.
EDIT:
I know the USB-A ports are working, tried them with my mouse. The USB-C Ports also work, they recognize my ubikey.
sudo journalctl  --follow does not output anything if i plug in the microphone directly into the laptop, but if i use a usb-c dock, i get the following:
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: hub 2-2.3:1.0: hub_ext_port_status 

failed (err = -71)
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: hub 2-2.3:1.0: hub_ext_port_status failed (err = -71)
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 11
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2: USB disconnect, device number 12
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.2: USB disconnect, device number 13
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.3: USB disconnect, device number 14
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 22
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2: USB disconnect, device number 23
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3: USB disconnect, device number 25
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 26
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os acpid[952]: input device has been disconnected, fd 21
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event18 - Generic USB Audio Consumer Control: device removed
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) config/udev: removing device Generic USB Audio Consumer Control
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Option "fd" "74"
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:82
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os acpid[952]: input device has been disconnected, fd 22
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event19 - Generic USB Audio: device removed
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) config/udev: removing device Generic USB Audio
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Option "fd" "98"
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:83
Jul 25 16:05:28 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.5: USB disconnect, device number 24
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0822, bcdDevice= 7.64
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3: Product: USB3.1 Hub             
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: hub 2-2.3:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: hub 2-2.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3: new high-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os boltd[1037]: probing: started [1000]
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2822, bcdDevice= 7.64
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: hub 1-2.3:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 25 16:05:29 pop-os kernel: hub 1-2.3:1.0: 5 ports detected
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0626, bcdDevice= 6.63
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2: Product: USB3.1 Hub
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: hub 2-2.3.2:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: hub 2-2.3.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0610, bcdDevice= 6.63
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2: Product: USB2.1 Hub
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2: Manufacturer: GenesysLogic
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: hub 1-2.3.2:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: hub 1-2.3.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.5: new high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.5: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=8822, bcdDevice= 0.01
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.5: Product: USB Billboard Device   
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.5: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.5: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
Jul 25 16:05:30 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3: new high-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=61.90
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: hub 1-2.3.2.3:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: hub 1-2.3.2.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0749, bcdDevice=15.39
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.2: Product: USB3.0 Card Reader
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.2: Manufacturer: Generic
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.2: SerialNumber: 000000001539
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32976]: checking bus 2, device 17: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3.2/2-2.3.2.2"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32976]: bus: 2, device: 17 was not an MTP device
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:          type_id=33 bits_offset=952
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:  
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: Invalid name
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: 
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: failed to validate module [usb_storage] BTF: -22
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:          type_id=33 bits_offset=952
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:  
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: Invalid name
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: 
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: failed to validate module [usb_storage] BTF: -22
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153, bcdDevice=31.00
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=7
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.3: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 2-2.3.2.3: SerialNumber: 001300E04CA51820
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32978]: checking bus 2, device 17: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3.2/2-2.3.2.2"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32978]: bus: 2, device: 17 was not an MTP device
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32979]: checking bus 2, device 18: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3.2/2-2.3.2.3"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32979]: bus: 2, device: 18 was not an MTP device
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:          type_id=2041 bitfield_size=0 bits_offset=192
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:  
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: Invalid name
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: 
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: failed to validate module [mii] BTF: -22
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:          type_id=2041 bitfield_size=0 bits_offset=192
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:  
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: Invalid name
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: 
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: failed to validate module [mii] BTF: -22
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3.1: new high-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:          type_id=2041 bitfield_size=0 bits_offset=192
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:  
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: Invalid name
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: 
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: failed to validate module [mii] BTF: -22
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:          type_id=2041 bitfield_size=0 bits_offset=192
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF:  
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: Invalid name
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: BPF: 
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: failed to validate module [mii] BTF: -22
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32983]: checking bus 2, device 18: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3.2/2-2.3.2.3"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32983]: bus: 2, device: 18 was not an MTP device
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=4ef0, bcdDevice= 0.04
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3.1: Product: USB Audio
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: usb 1-2.3.2.3.1: Manufacturer: Generic
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: input: Generic USB Audio Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb1/1-2/1-2.3/1-2.3.2/1-2.3.2.3/1-2.3.2.3.1/1-2.3.2.3.1:1.0/0003:0BDA:4EF0.0013/input/input35
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: input: Generic USB Audio as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb1/1-2/1-2.3/1-2.3.2/1-2.3.2.3/1-2.3.2.3.1/1-2.3.2.3.1:1.0/0003:0BDA:4EF0.0013/input/input36
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os kernel: hid-generic 0003:0BDA:4EF0.0013: input,hiddev5,hidraw11: USB HID v1.11 Device [Generic USB Audio] on usb-0000:c1:00.3-2.3.2.3.1/input0
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32988]: checking bus 1, device 31: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb1/1-2/1-2.3/1-2.3.2/1-2.3.2.3/1-2.3.2.3.1"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32988]: bus: 1, device: 31 was not an MTP device
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Generic USB Audio Consumer Control (/dev/input/event18)
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Generic USB Audio Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Generic USB Audio Consumer Control'
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82 fd 80 paused 0
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Generic USB Audio Consumer Control: always reports core events
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event18 - Generic USB Audio Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event18 - Generic USB Audio Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event18 - Generic USB Audio Consumer Control: device removed
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb1/1-2/1-2.3/1-2.3.2/1-2.3.2.3/1-2.3.2.3.1/1-2.3.2.3.1:1.0/0003:0BDA:4EF0.0013/input/input35/event18"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Generic USB Audio Consumer Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event18 - Generic USB Audio Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event18 - Generic USB Audio Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Generic USB Audio (/dev/input/event19)
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Generic USB Audio: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Generic USB Audio'
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event19 13:83 fd 98 paused 0
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Generic USB Audio: always reports core events
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event19"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event19 - Generic USB Audio: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event19 - Generic USB Audio: device is a keyboard
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event19 - Generic USB Audio: device removed
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb1/1-2/1-2.3/1-2.3.2/1-2.3.2.3/1-2.3.2.3.1/1-2.3.2.3.1:1.0/0003:0BDA:4EF0.0013/input/input36/event19"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Generic USB Audio" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event19 - Generic USB Audio: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1938]: (II) event19 - Generic USB Audio: device is a keyboard
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32995]: checking bus 1, device 31: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c1:00.3/usb1/1-2/1-2.3/1-2.3.2/1-2.3.2.3/1-2.3.2.3.1"
Jul 25 16:05:31 pop-os mtp-probe[32995]: bus: 1, device: 31 was not an MTP device


It sounds odd that nothing shows up on the Linux system. Have you tried to plug in a known working USB device like a USB-Drive (a USB/MSC device) with exactly the same USB cable and exactly the same port on the Linux box? Then monitor the Linux box w/something like "udevadm monitor" as you did before with the microphone? My only other guess is that the microphone requires more than 500mA to operate (assuming you are using a USB 2.0 port on the Linux box).  Which is hard to believe. Or the microphone is not presenting its self as a USB device initially.

Keep an eye on the terminal command sudo journalctl  --follow as you connect the microphone. If Ubuntu sees it, it will be  logged. Depending on what you find,  ... . Please [edit] your Question to add information.  Do not reply via Add Comment.
